# the last called function on mono touch-iphone platform

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

Are there any method , or methods which are called on when the user clicks home button or when the application crashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the UIApplicationDelegate.DidEnterBackground is invoked on your app before it goes to the background:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm?UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground:

Nothing is called if your application crashes.

Comment: I am not sure but I remember there is a method specially called on crashes. If i find it I will share as a comment here...  @miguel.de.icaza, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, like a managed exception, you can set the `[AppDomain.UnhandledException][1]` event to be notified - but there's not a lot you can do at this stage.

However that does **not** cover crashes that will occurs in native code. There are products that can log and report such crashes but they won't let you execute your own code (and can't for many crashes like out of memory conditions).

E.g. [How to capture iOS crashes in MonoTouch application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7989444/220643)